# User Profile properties not rendering as searchable links

Tags: 2010, search, user-profile

My user profile page renders user profiles using the following code

```
<SPSWC:ProfilePropertyValue PropertyName="DDI" dir="ltr" runat="server"/>
```

however in one environment the results are plain text

```
<div>DDI : 123 456 789</div>
```

and the other

```
<div>DDI : <a href='http://spportal/search/Pages/peopleresults.aspx?k="123%20456%20789"'>123 456 789</a></div>
```

While the search url brings back results in both environments, prooving that the profiles are set up and the information searchable,
I cannot seem to find the SharePoint setting that changes this rendering behaviour.

Note: The users email address and manager property render correctly (as mailto and user profile links respectively) so it appears to be some search setting I am forgetting.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, so you need to set the "Preferred Search Center".

go to:

Central Administration->Service Applications->User Profile Service Application->Setup My sites

This is a url to the page you wish the search results to appear on.